# Elif statement skipped

Tags: python

```
while True:
    top_of_range = input("Type a number from 1-10: ")

    if top_of_range.isdigit():
        top_of_range = int(top_of_range)
        break

    elif top_of_range.isdigit():
      int(top_of_range) <= 0
      print("Please type a number larger than 0.")
      continue
    
    else:
        print("Please type a number.")
        continue
```

if I type a value <= 0 , It just bypasses to "Please type a number."

Expecting it to show "Please type a number larger than 0." and loop back to the input.

Comment: Did you mean `elif int(top_of_range) <= 0:`?

Comment: If I change it to that and the user typer a letter "f", an error pops up.

Exception has occurred: ValueError
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'f'
  File "C:\Users\Michael Cheng\OneDrive\Desktop\RNG.py", line 11, in <module>
    elif int(top_of_range) <= 0:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'f'

Comment: The conditions on the `if` and `elif` are identical.  Surely that's a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that only one branch of an if/elif/else can actually be evaluated. You may also wish to simply try to convert input to int, and handle the exception if needed.

By raising `ValueError` on the input not being in range, you can handle both errors at the same time.

```
def get_number_in_range(bot, top):
  while True:
    try:
      n = int(input(f"Type a number from {bot}-{top}: "))
      if n < bot or n > top: raise ValueError
      return n
    except ValueError:
      print("Please type a valid number.")
```